# Pandas: Sort by sum of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a DataFrame:

```
COL1 COL2
   1    1
   3    1
   1    3
```

I need to sort by COL1 + COL2.

*key=lambda col: f(col)* argument-function of *sort_values(...)* lets you sort by a changed column but in the described case I need to sort on the basis of 2 columns. So, it would be nice if there were an opportunity to provide a *key* argument-function for 2 or more columns but I don't know whether such a one exists.

So, how can I sort its rows by sum COL1 + COL2?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
data = {"Column 1": [1, 3, 1], "Column 2": [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sorted_indices = (df["Column 1"] + df["Column 2"]).sort_values().index

df.loc[sorted_indices, :]
```

I just created a series that has the sum of both the columns, sorted it, got the sorted indices, and printed those indices out for the dataframe.

*(I changed the data a little so you can see the sorting in action. Using the data you provided, you wouldn't have been able to see the sorted data as it would have been the same as the original one.)*

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a unique index, you can also conveniently use the `key` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to pass a callable to apply to the `by` column. Here we can `add` the other column:

```
df.sort_values(by='COL1', key=df['COL2'].add)
```

We can even generalize to any number of columns using [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.sort_index(key=df.sum(1).get)
```

Output:

```
   COL1  COL2
0     1     1
2     1     3
1     3     2
```

Used input:

```
data = {"COL1": [1, 3, 1], "COL2": [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! The .set_index(...) with .sum(1) is just what is needed!