# Sorting a pandas dataframe based on the sum of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have got the following code which creates the dataframe shown in the attached image:

```
d = []

for i in range(5): 
    d.append({
                'a': np.random.rand(), 
                'b': np.random.rand(), 
                'c': np.random.rand(), 
                'd': np.random.rand(), 

                })

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to sort this in ascending order based on the sum of the 'c' and 'd' columns.

The final dataframe should still have 4 columns but just in sorted order.

I know `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values` exists but not sure how to use it for my case.

Thankyou.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Sort by sum of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71776214/pandas-sort-by-sum-of-2-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
d['e'] = d["c"] + d["d"]
d.sort_values("e").drop("e", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Also, this SO link show how to do this without creating a new column https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776590/14066512